# Windows 10 upgrade window says: [Download starting...] but nothing happens

Tags: windows, windows-10

I click on the system icon (right bottom, taskbar) to upgrade to Windows 10.
Then I get exactly this window:

[image]

I waited, and waited. I opened the command prompt (cmd.exe) and used the *netstat* command to see whether there are even any active internet connections.
(And I had no other programs open)
And yes, there was internet activity.
But still nothing happened.
What should I do?

Comment: how long did you wait? how fast is your internet connection usually?

Comment: Isn't today the last day Windows 10 will be free? Or did it stop today?

Comment: @HatsuneVocaloidMiku Its on the 29th I believe.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I thought it was somewhere around here. Try using Windows Media Creation Tool and create an installer from a usb stick. You can find it on the Microsoft site.

Comment: It takes quite a lot to upgrade to Win10 (couple of good hours) and if you have a slow internet connection just leave it on and go do your other jobs.

Comment: I also used the media creation tool. It worked for the first few steps (downloading, validating the download) and then, it said 'checking for new updates' and then it was stuck. It hung for 2 hours, and not just any progress was made. It's just messing up the disc. When I decided to close the tool, it said: 'It is first cleaned properly before closing the Setup, this can take a few minutes'. I waited another hour (around 80 minutes) but even then nothing happens. Then I shut down my computer, because I'm pretty sure it's just stuck/hanging/blocking/lazy

Comment: So: upgrading with the media creation tool: fails.
Upgrading with the taskbar-icon-tool: fails

Comment: get the clean Windows 10 ISO: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench, mount ISO, run setup.exe and select upgrade